# How to only accept certificates issued by user-specified CA per domain?

Tags: browser, ssl, certificate, https, ssl-certificate

## Question

Is it possible in Chromium or Firefox to only accept SSL certificates issued by a user-specified CA for a specific domain?

## Background

When you have set up your own certificate authority and you're issuing certificates for https servers you often want to make sure on the client side that no certificate issued by another CA is accepted. This can help to prevent man in the middle attacks.